# Unable to set Photos system library

Tags: macos, photos

I moved my Photos library to an external drive due to it's size.  I removed ~/Pictures/Photos Library.  When I launch Photos it asks to choose library.  I select "Other Library" and traverse to external drive where I select the photo library I moved.  Everything works as expected.  I then choose Photos preferences and and select "Use as System Photo Library".

The next time I launch Photos it cannot find the library and I have to go through the above sequence again.  I removed ~/Library/Prefernces/com.apple.Photos.plist and redid the procedure above.  When I check com.apple.Photos.plist it has the path to the external library.  Yet when I launch Photos it again says it can't find ~/Pictures/Photos Library.

Any recommendations what to try next?

Answer (score 1):

This might be simpler using [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) from the App Store [freeware]

A search [including invisibles] for `apple.photos` immediately after launching Photos holding  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd> , then quitting, shows several modified files, including

`~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Photos/Data/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Photos.savedState`
`/private/var/folders/nc/c83zpk8x7kd9qrxrd3nnbfym0000gn/T/com.apple.Photos.librarychooserservice`

It might be useful [after making sure you have a good backup] to test out some of those. SavedState is always a prime candidate for this type of thing, I'm less sure about the chooserservice, but it sounds apropos.

Comment: I renamed ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Photos to ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.bPhoto.  Then when I launch Photos it is pointing correctly to the external drive.  In looking at the contents of com.apple.Photo there is a directory Data that contains links to ../../../../Pictures.  My guess is this is what was causing issue.  When launched Photos it did not create com.apple.Photos. This must not be needed as Photos is working fine.